# DatabaseError : “not all arguments converted during string formatting” when I use pandas.io.sql.to_sql()

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy, web-crawler

I have a table:[image]

And I try to use this import this table by sqlalchemy , the code is:

```
import sqlalchemy as db
import pandas.io.sql as sql

username = 'root'     
password = 'root'     
host = 'localhost'    
port = '3306'         
database = 'classicmodels'   

engine = db.create_engine(f'mysql+pymysql://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}')

con = engine.raw_connection() 

#readinto dataframe
df = pd.read_sql(f'SELECT * FROM `{database}`.`offices`;', con)
print(df[:2])
df_append = pd.DataFrame([{'officeCode': 8,'city':'Taipei',
                           'phone':'1234567891','addressLine1':'Taipei DaAn',
                           'addressLine2':'Taipei DaAn2','state':'Taipei',
                           'country':'Taiwan','postalCode':'123','territory':'Asia'}])
df2 = pd.concat([df,df_append],ignore_index=True)
sql.to_sql(frame = df2, name='proj55.address_book5',con=con, if_exists='append',index=False)
```

But I always encounter these errors:

- If I pass `con = engine.raw_connection()` to `to_sql()`, I'll get this:

  - DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM
    sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': not all arguments
    converted during string formatting
- If I use `con = engine.connect()`, and pass to `read_sql()`, I'll get error:

  - AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'cursor'
- If I pass `engine` to  `to_sql()` and `read_sql()`, I'll get this:

  - AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'cursor'

What should I do?

Comment: Try passing your `engine` variable to `read_sql` and `to_sql` instead of passing `con`. `con` is a raw DBAPI connection, not a SQLAlchemy `Connectable` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pandas.read_sql use either:

- a sqlalchemy connection object `engine.connect()`
- a db api object *only for sqlite*

by using `raw_connection()`, you have a db api connection object, so pandas believes it's a connection to a sqlite database (as we see in your error `FROM sqlite_master WHERE` )

you need to use `con = engine.connect()`

```py
import sqlalchemy
import pandas
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('...')
with engine.connect() as conn:
    print('sqla:', list(conn.execute('select * from users')))
    df = pandas.read_sql('select * from users', conn)
    print('df:', df)
    df.to_sql('users2', conn)
    print('sqla:', list(engine.connect().execute('select * from users2')))
```

outputs:

```
sqla: [(1, 'toto'), (2, 'titi'), (3, 'tutu'), (4, 'tata')]
df:    id  name
0   1  toto
1   2  titi
2   3  tutu
3   4  tata
sqla: [(1, 'toto'), (2, 'titi'), (3, 'tutu'), (4, 'tata')]
```

as expected

Comment: Yup. We can also just pass the `engine` itself.

Comment: If I use `engine.connect()`, I'll get error: `AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'cursor'` from `pd.read_sql()` @Cyril Jouve

Answer (score 1):

you have to put list.string.sql fro it's given value n-1